# Is common values shared across String-Array possible in Android XML?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

For my Android development, I have 2 arrays which is very identical except for the first and last value as below.

```
<string-array name="minvalues">
    <item>Any Value</item>
    <item>100</item>
    <item>200</item>
    <item>300</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="maxvalues">
    <item>100</item>
    <item>200</item>
    <item>300</item>
    <item>Any Value</item>
</string-array>
```

I'm thinking is there a way to define the common values i.e. 100, 200, 300 as another array and have the `minvalues` and `maxvalues` *include* it from it, so we could share the common values across `minvalues` and `maxvalues`. Is this possible in Android arrays xml?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is, since the values are string, you will need to manually convert them to integers in order to look for common values using

```
String[] minValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.minvalues);
String[] maxValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.maxvalues);
```

and then convert them into int with

```
int[] minValsInt = Arrays.asList(minValues).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
int[] maxValuesInt = Arrays.asList(maxValues).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

now you can loop through each one and get the common values.

**Edit**
Here's the way to get the duplicates from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379510/finding-duplicate-values-between-two-arrays)

```
void findDupes(int[] a, int[] b) {
HashSet<Integer> map = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i : a)
    map.add(i);
for (int i : b) {
    if (map.contains(i))
        // found duplicate!    
}
```

}

Cheers

Comment: Android supports JDK 8, now?

Comment: Thanks snowman. Sorry for not making my question clear enough. My question is not finding the common, but not towards writing the common array, and have 2 arrays includes it, where by one will insert ANY as the first value, and the second will include ANY as the last value. I would like to do this in the resource XML. I have edited my question changing the "Decouple" word to "Define". Hopes this is clearer now. Thanks.