# How to compare two large array lists efficient in java

Tags: java, arraylist

so I have 2 large arraylists of objects of A 500k and B 900k in size and I want to create a 3rd list (c) of all the dups of A in B.

So I've been doing

```
    for(obj as:B)
    {

        if(!A.contains(as.getA()))
        {
            C.add(as);
        }

    }
```

But this takes quite a bit of time to process. Would maps or sets be quicker or any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379510/finding-duplicate-values-between-two-arrays

Comment: If they are sortable, sort them first then use a binary search (see Collections class).  If you can deal with the overhead of putting them in a `Set` then see the answer by @Kushan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HashSet` collection

```
List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
myList.addAll(listA);
myList.addAll(listB);

Set<MyClass> mySet = new HashSet<MyClass>(myList);
```

Comment: Since duplicates are desired should use `myList.retainAll(listB)` ?

Comment: retainAll means removes from the list all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection